# Proper way of destroying window resources

Tags: windows, winapi, resources

This is excerpt from my code based on win32 api:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void __fastcall TMyThread::Execute(void)
{
   WNDCLASSEX wc     = {0};
   wc.cbSize         = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
   wc.lpfnWndProc    = WindowProc;
   wc.hInstance      = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
   wc.lpszClassName  = class_name.c_str();

   if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
   {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
      return;
   }

   hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, class_name.c_str(), NULL, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);
   if (hwnd == NULL)
   {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
      return;
   }

   MSG msg;
   BOOL ret;
   while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0)
   {
      if (ret != -1)
      {
         TranslateMessage(&msg);
         DispatchMessage(&msg);
      }
   }
}
```

My questions:

1. Is it required to do some resource cleanup after quitting message loop (like CloseHandle for example)? Quite often i am seeing code samples without any such things. Is it correct?
2. Can newly created window receive messages into thread queue before first call of GetMessage function (we suppose that window was successfully created i.e. function CreateWindowEx returned without errors)?

Please take in mind that TMyThread is not main thread of application. So it can be created and destroyed many times in one application run. Please don't pay attention to quite simplified window creation. This particular window is not meant to be visible on screen. It is created solely for purpose of receiving messages from another application. This is highlighted by using HWND_MESSAGE value of hWndParent parameter when calling CreateWindowEx function.

Comment: Since you seem to be creating a window for the sole purpose of receiving messages on a thread I should point out that this is not strictly necessary. Any thread can receive messages posted to it using [`PostThreadMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946.aspx) (restrictions apply).

Comment: @IInspectable: I have considered this option. It's complicated because other application had to know thread ID when posting message to thread. On the other hand when posting message to window, I can find it through FindWindow function which is convenient and very reliable (I use window class name as unique ID).

Answer (score 1):

By creating, running and destroying thread in the above example again and again I have found out that two methods needs to be called after quitting from message loop. First is *DestroyWindow* and second is *UnregisterClass*. In regular application *DestroyWindow* function [should be called](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#destroying_win) in WM_CLOSE handler after the user confirms that he really wants to close the application. *DestroyWindow* function then sends WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY messages to window. In response to WM_DESTROY message application should call *PostQuitMessage(0)* function which results to immediately quitting message loop. So this part of code is not neccessary in all scenarios. I needed to call *DestroyWindow* function explicitly because I exit message loop by simply sending WM_QUIT message. When not doing it sometimes I received error 1412 (ERROR_CLASS_HAS_WINDOWS) when trying to unregister window class.

```
if (hwnd != NULL)
{
   ret = DestroyWindow(hwnd);
   if (ret == 0)
   {
      str.printf(L"Window destroying failed (GetLastError = %d)!", GetLastError());
      ShowError(str);
   }
   hwnd = NULL;
}

ret = UnregisterClass(class_name.c_str(), wc.hInstance);
if (ret == 0)
{
   str.printf(L"Window class unregistration failed (GetLastError = %d)!", GetLastError());
   ShowError(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be very careful with resources in Win32.  Make sure you've looked at the documentation carefully to determine what Windows itself will unload for you and what you have to unload yourself.

For examples, `HWND`s will get destroyed as parent `HWND`s get destroyed.

The best trick is to attempt to unload everything you've personally created.  If you get an error returned from a particular function on unload, you likely should not unload it as it's been unloaded by Windows or some related resource.

It is important not to unload things when it is not necessary, as that could cause a crash.

So for example, an icon created with a window that's directly from a resource likely shouldn't be unloaded.  But an `HBITMAP` you create that you draw to other windows, should most definitely be unloaded.

Your section question can be determined by a quick test with breakpoints.  I do not know off the top of my head.